# Does proclaimed belief in the oneness of God bring a non-Muslim closer to the Ummah?

Tags: shahada, ummah

A person becomes Muslim by showing he believes "There is no god but God and Muhammad is the messenger of God". Given that socio-political custom is a construct of peoples' different geographic and temporal experiences, would the proclamation of the tahlila - showing a belief in Tawheed - bring a non-Muslim any closer to the Ummah?

In reverse, if a person of Muslim heritage chooses to only state the first half of the Shahadah, where does he stand?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE. Please consider taking your time and take our [tour], check our [help] and [meta] to learn more about this site.

Answer (score 1):

Islam is only entered by stating the full testimony, not half or part of it. This is spiritual testification and physical testification. 
A person's utterance of the statement is ***accepted*** and ***true*** if they believe in the statement when uttering it.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam, which differs a lot from the usual internet forum. I strongly recommend you to take our [tour], check our [help], take a look at [meta] and read [answer] to learn more about this site and what we expect good answers to look like.

Comment: My question is more about what categories Islam has for that which is not Islam. So the people of the book follow the Abrahamic religions and are given advantages over "non-book" religious peoples and those beyond (atheists, I guess!). However - what defines a person of the book? Is it the cultural tradition or the tahlila?

Comment: .. I can imagine Jewish and Christian people happily swearing "There is no god but God" but adding a different addendum (".., and Israel is the chosen nation of God" for the Jews, ".., and Christ is the son of God" for the Christians (as much that notion chooses to fight with Tawheed!). What if you are outside of the Abrahamic religions but still accept the tahlila as true, but without aligning yourself to any one culture exclusively?

Comment: @IlyaGrushevskiy maybe they are named/called "khanif" and as i know prophet ibrahim is called/named so in quran.